# Git Pull removendo arquivos

Tags: git

Estou com o seguinte problema: Estou realizando um `git pull` e ao trazer do servidor algo, o `commit` esta automaticamente removendo arquivos.

Exemplo :

```
 removing Projeto/arquivoX
 removing Projeto/arquivoY
```

Comment: E qual é sua pergunta?

Comment: Ocorreu algo semelhante no meu projeto. 
Por alguma razão arquivos de mesmo nome porém de caso sensitivo diferentes o git considera como arquivos diferentes. Então ao deletar um arquivo e realizar push, outros usuários, por exemplo de windows, que possuem sistema operacional que não reconhece com dois arquivos diferentes, ao realizar pull tiveram seus arquivos deletados. Por exemplo: "modulo.c" e "Modulo.c" podem existir no repositorio git porém somente um arquivo pode existir no windows, gerando este comportamento.

É este o seu caso?

Answer (score 1):

Nas alterações acima de sua revisão, esses arquivos foram removidos?

Analise as revisões acima, e veja se algum *commit* existe com essas remoções. Se existir, logicamente estes arquivos vão ser removidos do seu repositório local.